# a word describing YouTube bad content

Tags: word-request

What is a word that can best describe YouTube bad content such as pranking videos, which negatively affect children?

I thought about the word banal but it doesn't seem to fit.

[Edit] As we know that children love to imitate actions they like, I'm implying the fact that this content, which get a lot of views by children, detrimentally affect children's personalities by persuading them to normalize inappropriate actions such as filming people on the street, generally invade other's privacies, bully or being offensive to others. Moreover, I'm comparing this type of content to the informative content on YouTube such educational videos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Banal" would mean "dull, uninteresting, and generally pointless". I think you're looking for something more like ["malicious"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/malicious):

> The worst thing about those **malicious** videos of children doing terrible things to strangers, is that their **notoriety** might inspire other children to do the same.

Other possibilities: *nasty, immoral, vicious, mischievous, awful, heinous, ugly, vile, depraved, offensive, disgusting* and various others.

Each of these can have a different nuance, but if you explain *exactly* what you want to say, I might be able to point to one of them as the most appropriate -- for example, do you want to focus more on the *immorality* of the acts show in the videos, or on how they *offend* you personally?

[Edit] As you might expect there is no single word to describe everything you want to say.  However you might try some combination of these:

> [**irresponsible**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/irresponsible) (adj): not thinking carefully enough or not caring about what might result from actions taken
>
> [**frivolous**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/frivolous) (adj): (of people) behaving in a silly and foolish way, or (of activities or objects) silly or unimportant:
>
> [**infamous**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/infamous) (adj): well known for something bad; notorious:
>
> [**seductive**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/seductive#dataset-cald4) (adj): making you want to do, have, or believe something, because of seeming attractive:

For example:

> While these videos might seem like so much harmless **frivolity**, they encourage **irresponsible** behavior among young people who have yet to develop the **moral compass** to distinguish the **malicious** from the benign.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Andrew. I was specifically describing the content itself. "YouTube ___ content affects children negatively. Examples of this type of content include: pranking videos, try not to laugh videos, etc..." I mean a totally different content than violent or sexual content.

Comment: @GhassanSaeed  well, "pranking" videos can be harmful.  Could you explain in a sentence exactly what you are trying to say about this content?  It's not clear how "joke" videos can be harmful to children.

Comment: as we know that children love to imitate actions they like, Im implying the fact that this content, which get a lot of views by children, detrimentally affect children's personalities by persuading them to normalize inappropriate actions such as filming people on the street, generally invade other's privacies, bully or being offensive to others. Moreover, Im comparing this type of content to the informative content on YouTube such educational videos.

Comment: @GhassanSaeed  I have added this comment to the question and voted to reopen .  I've also edited my answer with some more appropriate examples, which you can use in conjunction with "malicious" or one of its synonyms.  "Irresponsible", however, covers most of what you want to say.

Comment: Irresponsible seems to fit perfectly. Thank you Mr. Andrew

Answer (score 1):

You could describe such content as being:

- **damaging**
- **harmful**
- **detrimental**
- **malignant**
- **poisoning**

For example -

> Content on YouTube which glorifies jokes at the expense of others has a detrimental effect on the mental health of younger viewers.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the catch-all phrase:

> "Content unsuitable for younger viewers"

Comment: Question: "What is a word that can best describe YouTube bad content such as pranking videos, which negatively affect children?
Answer: "Content unsuitable for younger viewers". This answer is somehow unhelpful and needs to be downvoted??